# ASP.NET Web API Endpoint for querying MongoDB collections

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections in my database:

```
// UnifiedPost
public class UnifiedPost
{
    public UnifiedPost() { Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(); }

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public int OriginalId { get; set; }
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Preview { get; set; }
    [AlsoNotifyFor("IsVideo")]
    public string FullSized { get; set; }
    public char Rating { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public string Dimensions { get { return string.Format("{0}x{1}", Width, Height); } }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    [MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes.BsonIgnore]
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ObjectId> TagIds { get; set; }
    public char Site { get; set; }

    public bool IsVideo { get { return FullSized.Contains(".mp4") || FullSized.Contains(".webm"); } }

    public string UniversalId { get; set; } // UNIQUE index (Site + Original id; fe. S3001)
}

// Tag
public class Tag
{
    public Tag() { }

    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to create a WebAPI endpoint for querying the posts from the database:

```
[HttpGet, Route("post")]
public UnifiedPost[] GetPosts(string tags = null, string sites = "RSGLY", string rating = null,int page = 0, int limit = 100, string sort = "id:desc")
{
    if (limit == 0 || limit > 100) limit = 100;
    var toSkip = page * limit;
    var tagArray = tags.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var siteArray = sites.ToCharArray();
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var db = client.GetDatabase("Booru");
    var postsColl = db.GetCollection<UnifiedPost>("Posts");
    var tagsColl = db.GetCollection<BooruScraper.Models.Tag>("Tags");
    var tagIds = tagsColl.Find(o => tagArray.Contains(o.Name)).ToList().ToDictionary(o => o.Name, o => o.Id);

    var query = postsColl.Find<UnifiedPost>(o => siteArray.Contains(o.Site) && tagIds.Values.All(p => o.TagIds.Contains(p))).Project<UnifiedPost>(Builders<UnifiedPost>.Projection.Expression(p => new UnifiedPost()
    {
        FullSized = p.FullSized,
        Height = p.Height,
        Id = p.Id,
        OriginalId = p.OriginalId,
        Preview = p.Preview,
        Rating = p.Rating,
        Score = p.Score,
        Site = p.Site,
        TagIds = new ObjectId[0],
        Tags = string.Join(" ", tagsColl.Find(q => p.TagIds.Contains(q.Id), new FindOptions()).Project<string>(Builders<BooruScraper.Models.Tag>.Projection.Expression(r => r.Name)).ToList(CancellationToken.None)),
        Thumbnail = p.Thumbnail,
        UniversalId = p.UniversalId,
        Width = p.Width
    })).Skip(toSkip).ToList();
    return query.ToArray();
}
```

Frankly, this code is ugly and doesn't even achieve the minimum purpose. It's simply pathetic, but I can't think of any way to do this with fhe Find Fluent API.

For one, I want to filter all posts by tags entered by user, if no tags are entered, no filters are applied. But I have no idea how to achieve this, let alone how to apply all the other filters  (Sites, sort, page...) to a `find` query.

What am I missing here? If `Find` even what I should be using in this situation?

Thanks!

Edit: In the simplest terms possible, how do I:

1. From the entire collection of posts filter only the ones that match the entered tags;
2. From that result filter it even further to only the Sites that are entered by the user;
3. Further filter the collection and remove all posts that don't match the entered ratings;
4. Pages, limits etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riiiiiight. Where shall we start? ;)

Unless there is a specific reason why you need two separate collections I would recommend getting rid of the "Tags" collection. And even if you need it (e.g. in order to centrally manage the available tags or something) you'd want to duplicate the tag information in your UnifiedPost documents anyway. A document database is not built to support joins really.

Here is a working example that should give you an idea of how this could be built (I stripped down your entity to the relevant parts):

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class UnifiedPost
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string[] Tags { get; set; }
        public char Site { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<UnifiedPost>("test");

            collection.InsertOne(new UnifiedPost() { Site = 'X', Tags = new[] { "a" } });
            collection.InsertOne(new UnifiedPost() { Site = 'Y', Tags = new[] { "a", "b" } });
            collection.InsertOne(new UnifiedPost() { Site = 'Z', Tags = new[] { "a", "b", "c" } });

            // 1. first filter
            var tagsWeAreInterestedIn = new[] { "a", "b" };
            var tagsFilter = Builders<UnifiedPost>.Filter.All(up => up.Tags, tagsWeAreInterestedIn);

            // 2. second filter
            var sitesWeAreInterestedIn = new[] { 'X', 'Y' };
            var siteFilter = Builders<UnifiedPost>.Filter.In(up => up.Site, sitesWeAreInterestedIn);

            // 3. third filter: rating (would follow the exact same pattern as the sites filter so we skip that part)

            // search for combined filter
            var query = collection.Find(tagsFilter & siteFilter);

            // 4. paging (e.g. sorted by the Score property, 10 results per page, skipped to page 4)
            // please note: this example will not return any data with skip=3
            // because we do not insert enough test data - use skip(0) to get a result!
            query = query.SortBy(up => up.Score).Skip(3).Limit(10);

            var postsWithTagB = query.ToList();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that actually does make sense! Still, I already switched to SQL Server and with legit relations it's much easier. The downside? The Database Server thing takes 5GB and the entire database with the relation and all index is 3 times as large as the entire MongoDB with slightly more documents. My VPS suffers, I'm worrying about every megabyte now, but at least the filtering is much simpler, and it also seems to be faster.

Comment: If your are concerned about space you would want to add this before you access MongoDB: `ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreIfDefault", new ConventionPack { new IgnoreIfDefaultConvention(true) }, t => true);` This will make the Serializer ignore fields that have a default value. Also, maybe this helps: [link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-765) (bottom of the page has some code)